# Jquery and MYSQL and AJAX will not call functions by id

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to use jquery and ajax to update a mysql database.  I was able to add a new record and have the script append the html properly.  Now i need to add an ID to eacho row of the table so i can edit the information for any of the rows.  I'm calling the function editCompany(id) to pass the id to the script, but i cant get it to work.

When I run the script, I get an error "The value of the property editCompany() is null or undefined, not a function object"

Any thoughts?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$settings['title']?></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <style>
                body { font-size: 62.5%; }
                label, input { display:block; }
                input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
                fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
                h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
                div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
                div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
                div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
                .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
                .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
            </style>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    var company_name = $( "#company_name" ),
                    company_address = $( "#company_address" ),
                    company_city = $( "#company_city" ),
                    company_state = $( "#company_state" ),
                    company_zip = $( "#company_zip" ),
                    company_phone = $( "#company_phone" ),
                    company_fax = $( "#company_fax" ),
                    company_email = $( "#company_email" ),
                    company_website = $( "#company_website" ),
                    allFields = $( [] ).add( company_name ).add( company_address ).add( company_city ).add( company_state ).add( company_zip ).add( company_phone ).add( company_fax ).add( company_email ).add( company_website ),
                    tips = $( ".validateTips" );

                    function updateTips( t ) {
                        tips
                        .text( t )
                        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
                        }, 500 );
                    }
                    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
                        if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
                            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                            updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + "." );
                            //updateTips( n );
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
                        if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
                            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                            updateTips( n );
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    function ajaxFunction(){
                        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
                        try{
                            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        } catch (e){
                            // Internet Explorer Browsers
                            try{
                                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                            } catch (e) {
                                try{
                                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                } catch (e){
                                    // Something went wrong
                                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
                        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(company_id){
                            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                                if( ajaxResult == "success"){
                                    $( "#company-id-" + id ).html( "<tr>" + "<td>" + company_name.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_address.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_city.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_state.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_zip.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_phone.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_fax.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_email.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_website.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>" );
                                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
                                } else if ( ajaxResult == "failed" ) {
                                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
                                    alert("There was an error updating the information to the database.");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        var queryString = "?company_name=" + company_name.val() + "&company_address=" + company_address.val() + "&company_city=" + company_city.val() + "&company_state=" + company_state.val() + "&company_zip=" + company_zip.val() + "&company_phone=" + company_phone.val() + "&company_fax=" + company_fax.val() + "&company_email=" + company_email.val() + "&company_website=" + company_website.val();

                        ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax_add_company.php" + queryString, true);
                        ajaxRequest.send(null);
                    }

                    function editCompany(id) {
                        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            height: 300,
                            width: 350,
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                "Edit a Company": function() {
                                    var bValid = true;
                                    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_name, "Company Name", 3, 50 );
                                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_address, "Address", 3, 50 );
                                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_city, "City", 1, 50 );
                                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_state, "State", 2, 2 );
                                    bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_zip, "Zip Code", 1, 50 );
                                    bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( company_email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );

                                    if ( bValid ) {
                                        ajaxEditCompany(id);
                                    }
                                },
                                Cancel: function() {
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                }
                            },
                           close: function() {
                                allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                            }
                        });
                   }
                });
            </script>
        </head>
         <body>
            <div id="dialog-form" title="Edit Company Information">
            <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="name">Company Name</label>
                       <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="company_address">Company Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company_address" id="company_address" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="company_city">City</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company_city" id="company_city" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="company_state">State</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company_state" id="company_state" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="company_zip">Zip</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company_zip" id="company_zip" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="company_phone">Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company_phone" id="company_phone" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="company_fax">Fax</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company_fax" id="company_fax" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="company_email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company_email" id="company_email" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                        <label for="company_website">Website</label>
                        <input type="text" name="company_website" id="company_website" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="company-contain" class="ui-widget">
                <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
                <table id="companies" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Zip</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Fax</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Website</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="id-1">
                        <td>Ashton Martin</td>
                        <td>124 Main</td>
                        <td>Dallas</td>
                        <td>TX</td>
                        <td>75206</td>
                        <td>2148264955</td>
                        <td>2148264969</td>
                        <td>info@google.com</td>
                        <td>www.google.com</td>
                        <td><button onClick="editCompany('1');">Edit</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id-2">
                        <td>Mike Jones</td>
                        <td>124 Main</td>
                        <td>Dallas</td>
                        <td>TX</td>
                        <td>75206</td>
                        <td>2148245654</td>
                        <td>2148232165</td>
                        <td>info@mikejones.com</td>
                        <td>www.google.com</td>
                        <td><button onClick="editCompany('2');">Edit</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="id-3">
                        <td>Nick Moore</td>
                        <td>124 Main</td>
                        <td>Dallas</td>
                        <td>TX</td>
                        <td>75206</td>
                        <td>2144584569</td>
                        <td>214789456</td>
                        <td>info@nickmoore.com</td>
                        <td>www.google.com</td>
                        <td><button onClick="editCompany('3');">Edit</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>  
            $(document).ready(function(){   

                var company_name = $( "#company_name" ),
                    company_address = $( "#company_address" ),
                    company_city = $( "#company_city" ),
                    company_state = $( "#company_state" ),
                    company_zip = $( "#company_zip" ),
                    company_phone = $( "#company_phone" ),
                    company_fax = $( "#company_fax" ),
                    company_email = $( "#company_email" ),
                    company_website = $( "#company_website" ),
                    allFields = $( [] ).add( company_name ).add( company_address ).add( company_city ).add( company_state ).add( company_zip ).add( company_phone ).add( company_fax ).add( company_email ).add( company_website ),
                    tips = $( ".validateTips" );

                function updateTips( t ) {      
                    tips        
                        .text( t )
                        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );      
                    setTimeout(function() {        
                        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );      
                    }, 500 );    
                }     
                function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {      
                    if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {        
                        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );        
                        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + "." ); 
                        //updateTips( n );       
                        return false;      
                    } else {        
                        return true;      
                    }    
                }     
                function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {      
                    if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {        
                        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );        
                        updateTips( n );        
                        return false;     
                    } else {        
                        return true;      
                    }    
                }

                function getCompanyData(id){
                    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
                    try{
                        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } catch (e){
                        // Internet Explorer Browsers
                        try{
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e) {
                            try{
                                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            } catch (e){
                                // Something went wrong
                                alert("Your browser broke!");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
                    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                            var ajaxResult = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(ajaxResult);
                            $("#c_id").val(obj.company_id);
                            $("#company_name").val(obj.company_name);
                            $("#company_address").val(obj.company_address);
                            $("#company_city").val(obj.company_city);
                            $("#company_state").val(obj.company_state);
                            $("#company_zip").val(obj.company_zip);
                            $("#company_phone").val(obj.company_phone);
                            $("#company_fax").val(obj.company_fax);
                            $("#company_email").val(obj.company_email);
                            $("#company_website").val(obj.company_website);
                        } 
                    }

                    var queryString = "?company_id=" + id;
                    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax_get_companies.php" + queryString, true);
                    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
                }

                function ajaxFunction(){
                    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

                    try{
                        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } catch (e){
                        // Internet Explorer Browsers
                        try{
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e) {
                            try{
                                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            } catch (e){
                                // Something went wrong
                                alert("Your browser broke!");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
                    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                            var ajaxResult = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(ajaxResult);
                            if (ajaxResult == "failed") {
                                alert("There was an error updating the database.  Please try again.");
                            } else {
                        $( "#c_name-" + obj.company_id ).text( obj.company_name );
                        $( "#c_address-" + obj.company_id ).text( obj.company_address );
                        $( "#c_city-" + obj.company_id ).text( obj.company_city );
                        $( "#c_state-" + obj.company_id ).text( obj.company_state );
                        $( "#c_zip-" + obj.company_id ).text( obj.company_zip );
                        $( "#c_phone-" + obj.company_id ).text( obj.company_phone );
                        $( "#c_fax-" + obj.company_id ).text( obj.company_fax );
                        $( "#c_email-" + obj.company_id ).text( obj.company_email );
                        $( "#c_website-" + obj.company_id ).text( obj.company_website );
//                              $( "#company-row-" + obj.company_id ).html( "<td>" + obj.company_name + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.company_address + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.company_city + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.company_state + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.company_zip + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.company_phone + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.company_fax + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.company_email + "</td>" + "<td>" + obj.company_website + "</td>" + "<td><button class=company-edit-button data-id=514>Update Company</button></td>"  ); 
                                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var queryString = "?company_id=" + $("#c_id").val() + "&company_name=" + company_name.val() + "&company_address=" + company_address.val() + "&company_city=" + company_city.val() + "&company_state=" + company_state.val() + "&company_zip=" + company_zip.val() + "&company_phone=" + company_phone.val() + "&company_fax=" + company_fax.val() + "&company_email=" + company_email.val() + "&company_website=" + company_website.val();
                    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax_edit_company.php" + queryString, true);
                    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
                }


                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({      
                    autoOpen: false,      
                    height: 300,      
                    width: 350,      
                    modal: true,      
                    buttons: {        
                        "Save": function() {          
                            var bValid = true;          
                            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );           

                            bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_name, "Company Name", 3, 50 );
                            bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_address, "Address", 3, 50 );
                            bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_city, "City", 3, 50 );
                            bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_state, "State", 2, 2 );
                            bValid = bValid && checkLength( company_zip, "Zip Code", 1, 50 );          

                            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( company_email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );          
                            //bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );          
                            //bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( company_address, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Address field only allows numbers and letters" );           

                            if ( bValid ) {            
                                ajaxSend = ajaxFunction();
                            }        
                        },        
                        Cancel: function() {          
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );        
                        }      
                    },      
                    close: function() {        
                        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );      
                    }    
                });     
                $(".company-edit-button").click(function(){
                    var id = $(this).data("id");                
                    getCompanyResults = getCompanyData(id);
                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                });
            });  
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">  
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>   
        <form>  
            <fieldset>  
                <input type="hidden" name="c_id" id="c_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />  
                <label for="name">Company Name</label>    
                <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />    
                <label for="company_address">Company Address</label>    
                <input type="text" name="company_address" id="company_address" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />    
                <label for="company_city">City</label>    
                <input type="text" name="company_city" id="company_city" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />   
                <label for="company_state">State</label>    
                <input type="text" name="company_state" id="company_state" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />   
                <label for="company_zip">Zip</label>    
                <input type="text" name="company_zip" id="company_zip" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />   
                <label for="company_phone">Phone</label>    
                <input type="text" name="company_phone" id="company_phone" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />   
                <label for="company_fax">Fax</label>    
                <input type="text" name="company_fax" id="company_fax" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />   
                <label for="company_email">Email</label>    
                <input type="text" name="company_email" id="company_email" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />   
                <label for="company_website">Website</label>    
                <input type="text" name="company_website" id="company_website" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />   

            </fieldset>  
        </form>
    </div>  

    <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">  
        <h1>Existing Users:</h1>  
            <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">    
                <thead>      
                    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">        
                        <th>Name</th>        
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Zip</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Fax</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Wesbite</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>    
                </thead>    
                <tbody>      
                    <tr>        
                        <td id="c_name-514">Ashton Wynne</td>        
                        <td id="c_address-514">124 Main</td> 
                        <td id="c_city-514">Dallas</td> 
                        <td id="c_state-514">TX</td> 
                        <td id="c_zip-514">75206</td> 
                        <td id="c_phone-514">2148264955</td> 
                        <td id="c_fax-514">2148264969</td> 
                        <td id="c_email-514">info@ashtonwynne.com</td> 
                        <td id="c_website-514">www.google.com</td>
                        <td><button class="company-edit-button" data-id="514">Update Company</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="c_name-515">Ashton Wynne</td>        
                        <td id="c_address-515">124 Main</td> 
                        <td id="c_city-515">Dallas</td> 
                        <td id="c_state-515">TX</td> 
                        <td id="c_zip-515">75206</td> 
                        <td id="c_phone-515">2148264955</td> 
                        <td id="c_fax-515">2148264969</td> 
                        <td id="c_email-515">info@ashtonwynne.com</td> 
                        <td id="c_website-515">www.google.com</td>
                        <td><button class="company-edit-button" data-id="515">Update Company</button></td>
                    </tr>      
                </tbody>  
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is not defined because you have some punctuation mistakes.  For example:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(company_id){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        if( ajaxResult == "success"){
            $( "#company-id-" + id ).html( "<tr>" + "<td>" + company_name.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_address.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_city.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_state.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_zip.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_phone.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_fax.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_email.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_website.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>" );
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
        } else if ( ajaxResult == "failed" ) {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
            alert("There was an error updating the information to the database.");
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server

// Lighthart says: Semicolon missing near here.

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(company_id){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        if( ajaxResult == "success"){
            $( "#company-id-" + id ).html( "<tr>" + "<td>" + company_name.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_address.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_city.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_state.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_zip.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_phone.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_fax.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_email.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + company_website.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>" );
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
        } else if ( ajaxResult == "failed" ) {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
            alert("There was an error updating the information to the database.");
        }
    }
}
```

appears to be missing a semicolon.  Using a javascript linter shows myriad errors in your script portion.  Try out http://www.jshint.com/ and fix the errors you have.

Comment: This part of my code was working fine.  I'm having a problem with the editCompany() part of the script.

Comment: Also, i tried copying and pasting my code into the website you suggesteed (jhint.com) and couldnt get it to work.  do you paste the whole thing or just the stuff betwen the <script> and </script>

Comment: I understand that.  If you read my answer again, you will realize the reason you are having a problem with the editCompany() part of your script is that there _is no_ editCompany() part of your script.

Comment: To use jshint.com just post the stuff between the <script> </script> tags

Comment: I don't understand.  I have a function called "editCompany(id) in the Script.  I try to call it from the table by using onclick"editCompany('1')".

Comment: Your call to ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(company_id) { ..} is never properly terminated with a semicolon (see // Lighthart says: ..., above), and as such the text for the function is 'inside' this statement, and thus is part of this statement, not part of the lexical scope of your main script.  So when you call it from your body, it does not exist.